# Custom Tax Calculation infinite loop issue in Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, tax, plugin

Reason i used the following Plugin

We have a custom table,

Which has columns, quote_id, image_id, product_id.

We are showing a product in list page and detail page (which has Tax class 20%)

Once the product is added we are not adding that product into the cart, instead adding different product, that is not having tax(created a custom controller and adding the product pro grammatically) .

Upon adding the product we are updating the custom table with quote_id and image_id(the sku of main product shown in the list page) for the product.

Since the added product doesn't have the Tax class, so Tax is not being shown. so used the below plugin to fetch the Tax of main product(by Querying from the custom table).

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total">
    <plugin name="mbs_customtax_cart_item" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomTaxTotal" />
</type>
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/CustomTaxTotal.php**

```
class CustomTaxTotal{  

private $logger;   
protected $_productloader;
public $_cart;
public $customTax;
public $getTaxAmount;
protected $_resource;
protected $customerSession;
protected $_taxCalculation;
protected $_scopeConfig;
protected $_coreSession;
public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation $taxCalculation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_taxCalculation = $taxCalculation;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
}

public function calculateCustomTaxForQuote()
{
    $taxRate = 0;
    $taxAmount = 0;
    $itemPrice = 0;
    
    $this->logger->info('--getTaxAmount--'.$this->getTaxAmount);
    //$this->getTaxAmount = null;
    //if (is_null($this->customTax)) {
    if (is_null($this->getTaxAmount)) {
        //$this->getTaxAmount = $this->getTaxValue();       
        //$this->logger->info('--getTaxAmountSess--'.$this->getTaxAmount);
        //$this->customTax = 0;            
        $connection = $this->getConnection();           
        $quoteId = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getId();
        $this->logger->info('--quoteId--'.$quoteId);
        $binds_select_pod = array(
                'quote_id'    => $quoteId
            );              
            $isPodExistQry = "select * from pod_temp_cart where quote_id = :quote_id"; 
            $results_podexist = $connection->query($isPodExistQry,$binds_select_pod);
            $isPodExistRes = $results_podexist->fetchAll();
            
            if(isset($isPodExistRes) && count($isPodExistRes) > 0){
                foreach($isPodExistRes as $results){
                    $imageId = $results['image_id'];
                    $itemPrice = $results['price'];
                    $itemQty = $results['qty'];
                    $imageProductId = $this->getProductIdBySku($imageId);
                    $this->logger->info('--imageProductId--'.$imageProductId);
                    $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($imageProductId);
                    $taxRate = $this->getRate($product);
                    if($taxRate > 0){
                        $itemTax = ($itemPrice * $taxRate)/100;
                        $taxAmount += $itemTax;                         
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isset($taxAmount) && $taxAmount !='' && $taxAmount != 0) {
                $this->logger->info('--customTax--'.$taxAmount);
                //$this->setTaxValue($taxAmount);
                $this->getTaxAmount = $taxAmount;
                //return $taxAmount;
                $this->customTax = $taxAmount;                 
               return $this->customTax;
            }
    } 
}
public function getRate($product){
    $productTaxClassId = $product->getTaxClassId();     
    $shippingAddress = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getDefaultShippingAddress();
    $countryCode =  (isset($shippingAddress['country_id']) && !empty($shippingAddress['country_id'])) ? $shippingAddress['country_id']:'GB';
    $rate = $this->_taxCalculation->getRate(
        new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'country_id' => $countryCode,
                'customer_class_id' => $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('tax/classes/default_customer_tax_class'),
                'product_class_id' => $productTaxClassId
            ]
        )
    );
    return $rate;
}

public function beforeAddTotalAmount(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $subject,
    $code,
    $amount
) {
    if ($code == 'tax') {
        //$this->logger->info('--amount--'.$amount);
        $amount += $this->calculateCustomTaxForQuote();
    }
    return [$code, $amount];
}

public function beforeAddBaseTotalAmount(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $subject,
    $code,
    $amount
) {
    if ($code =='tax') {
        //$this->logger->info('--amount--'.$amount);
        $amount += $this->calculateCustomTaxForQuote();
    }

    return [$code, $amount];
}
public function getConnection(){
    return $this->_resource->getConnection();
}
public function getProductIdBySku($sku) {
    $product = $this->_productloader->create();
    $product->load($product->getIdBySku($sku));
    $productId = $product->getId();
    return $productId;
   }
 }
```

From the Above code I am getting the Correct Tax amount but once i click Place order getting the below error due to this unable to place the order.

Because $this->getTaxAmount is always null here, can anyone please help on this?

> Infinite loop detected,in exception file.

Please someone update me the working solution for this. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: are you able to describe a step by step instruction on how to repeat the issue you have? I am convinced you'd have help no doubt if we can repeat the issue on our environment

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy, yes, i am fetching tax info for the product from custom table, in that step getting this issue, how can i help you to replicate the issue, can we connect in skype?

Comment: no, I don't want to start babysitting you. You either are able to describe how the community can help or we cannot resolve your issue and we may have to close your post?

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy, yes, steps are simple
1. Product A, we are showing in list page(which has Tax class 20%)
2. Once the product is added we are not adding that product into the cart, instead adding different product, that is not having tax.

Comment: But we are maintaining a custom table with this product with the quote I'd, from there I am trying to get the product tax amount and show it for the product added in cart.

Comment: from the above plugin i am getting correct Tax amount, but i am unable to place the order, As i am getting above exception.

Comment: excellent, I suggest to update your question and write all this down on it. Then, I will follow all the steps you indicate: I am using Magento 2.3.3 and sample data, luma theme. You will have to be accurate so that on my envrionment I can also reproduce your issue. Maybe you might want to install bare install and tests your steps yourself?

Comment: Updated my question, please have a look. Thanks

Comment: if (is_null($this->customTax)) { this is always null, so its firing alwas that is causing infinite loop issue

Comment: I am sure you're issue is important and can be solved. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate it on my install and therefore cannot help

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy, if you give time, then i can replicate the issue for you. have u used my table? pls ping me your skype id or hangout, i will show you the issue please, its a serious issue , can u please help me on that?

Comment: is_null($this->customTax) is null always when clicked placed order, please help me only that issue, then its resolved.remaining everything working fine, but can't resolve the infinite loop issue.

Comment: will do as soon as you tell me a way to replicate the issue without working on your machine

Comment: i am not sure how u used in your machine, pls show me your system, then i will try to replicate.

Comment: can you connect on hangouts or skype and show me your system or share the url to replicate, that is the only way for me to help you to replicate

Comment: Already i told the steps, with that you couldn't reproduce, pls share the url then i will replicate the issue for you.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/110337/inifinite-loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110338/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-herve-tribouilloy).

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing happens because of this line in you code:

`$quoteId = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getId();`

Magento does a calculation of totals and taxes and loading the quote in you plugin causes it to enter in an infinite loop.

Since you need just the quote_id and not other information from the quote you can get that info from the checkout session without loading quote.

To do so you need to inject `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,` in you constructor and get the quote_id by using `$quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuoteId();`

In this way the quote will not be loaded and it will not enter in an infinite loop.